# Como optimizar fórmula para devolver valor de celda cuando se cumplen múltiples condiciones

Tags: excel, vba, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Busco una manera de optimizar una fórmula compuesta de excel ya que al usarla muchas veces el archivo se vuelve muy lento, tal vez al usarla en google spreadsheet los cálculos sean más rápidos pero no me funciono la misma fórmula o con algún código de VBA.

-El objetivo de la fórmula es realizar la suma condicional de la columna "B" cuando el valor en la columna "A" (Fecha) es mayor que el valor en la celda "D2" (fecha de inicio). Luego, compara si la suma es mayor o igual a 100 y devuelve la fecha de la columna "A" en la que el acumulado alcanzo 100 o más.
[image: formula]

La formula es `=INDICE($A$2:$A$1879,COINCIDIR(VERDADERO,SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($B$2:$B$1879,$A$2:$A$1879,"<="&$A$2:$A$1879,$A$2:$A$1879,">="&D2)>=100,0))`

Les agradecería sucualquier ayuda con la fórmula, como hacerla funcionar en google spreadsheet o con VBA.

Saludos.

Comment: Se puede llevar a VBA y quizás que te lo pegue como valor para que deje de consumir recursos. ¿Qué código has probado? ¿Qué errores obtienes?